# Buttons not responding to touch in scrollview

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a `UIView` in a `UIScrollView` and under the `UIView` there are some labels, and two buttons.
Everything works fine, except the buttons. They do not respond to touch.
Everything is done in `Storyboard` and the labels and buttons are all using `autoresize`

I have tried to add:

```
scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = true
scrollView.delaysContentTouches = true
```

To no effect.

The view hierarchy is as follows:

> -View
>   --Scroll View
>   ---View
>   ----Label
>   ----Label
>   ----More Labels
>   ----Button
>   ----Button

Comment: Your labels and buttons are subviews of `---View`? Which is itself a subview of `--Scroll View`? If so, set the background color of `---View` to something obvious (like red), and tell me if you see the red view at run-time.

Comment: I did, and that revealed some constraints issues. Sorten now. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Write your own class subclass UIScroll view and add below code

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view {
  return NO;
}
```

or modify your code

```
scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = false
scrollView.delaysContentTouches = false
```

Answer (score 0):

**The view hierarchy is as follows:**

#### -View

> 1.--Scroll
> 2---View .   <--- *Check this UIVIEW User interaction is Enable or disable*
> 3----Label
> 4----Label
> 5---More Labels
> 6----Button
> 7----Button